# Silverlight ScrollViewer or HorizontalScrollBar

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight-4.0

I have ScrollViewer and child Stack panel. I need my HorizontalScrollBar automatically scroll right when content added. How to do this? Items to stack panel added dynamically.
P.s. i am trying to use this.scrollViewer.ScrollToRight(); but it not always scrolls to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"myScroll" is the scroll viewer's name.

```
myScroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(myScroll.ExtentWidth);
```